# Concise way to write decision tree with height 2 in C

Tags: c, coding-style

I have a decision tree of height 2:

```
const BOOL isVerticalAnimationRequired = YES;
const BOOL isArgumentEditorExpanded = YES;
const BOOL isSelectionLeftToRight = YES;

UITableViewRowAnimation argumentEditorAnimation;
if (isVerticalAnimationRequired)
{
    argumentEditorAnimation = (isArgumentEditorExpanded) ? UITableViewRowAnimationTop :     UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
}
else
{
    argumentEditorAnimation = (isSelectionLeftToRight) ? UITableViewRowAnimationLeft : UITableViewRowAnimationRight;
}
```

My problem is that the code is verbose. Ideally I would like to declare and set `argumentEditorAnimation` in one statement.

Are there any clever C style tips for handling situation like this?

Comment: It's called ternary @larsmans

Comment: Grrr. Why do people always add Objective-C tags to C questions? <sarcasm>Seeing as Objective-C is a strict superset of C why not label all C questions with Objective-C too - in fact we should just ditch the C tag entirely!</sarcasm> Yes, I know that I've used enum values defined in an Objective-C framework but that's irrelevant to the nub of the question. I intentionally didn't add Objective-C because I'm asking about for specific C tips and I didn't want to scare of C gurus who may see the Objective-C tag and discard the question for being out their remit.

Comment: Benedict: Agreed that the tag doesn't fit. If you feel that an incorrect edit of your question was made, feel free to roll it back (I've done so). You can also address the editor using the `@` comment syntax, i.e., `@Dhaivat`, to express your opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would *not* try to fold this into one expression for reasons of clarity, but if you must:

```
argumentEditorAnimation =
  isVerticalAnimationRequired ?
      (isArgumentEditorExpanded ?
           UITableViewRowAnimationTop
        :  UITableViewRowAnimationBottom)
    : (isSelectionLeftToRight ?
           UITableViewRowAnimationLeft
         : UITableViewRowAnimationRight);
```

Alternatively, you can make your code more concise by dropping the `{}` when they're not needed.

(Consider using shorter identifiers if you want to write these kinds of expressions. The long identifiers make the code verbose as well. E.g., drop the `is` in your booleans.)

Answer (score 2):

*Sometimes* logic like this can best be expressed with a small table that you index with your decision criteria.

In this case, I would just use good formatting as larsmans showed in his answer.

Comment: When would you advise using a data driven?

Comment: It's pretty subjective.  In this case, I probably wouldn't because there are actually three variables to check.  At first glance I thought it was two variables and the mapping was essentially a truth table of two booleans.  Good candidates are ones that you would document with a table rather than text, ones in which the table is completely full (not sparse), and ones where the results are somewhat arbitrary or subject to change.  In extreme optimization situations, a table lookup can be faster then nested `if`s in cases where branch prediction doesn't help.